# git error - failed to push some refs to '**.git'

Tags: git

I am facing a problem that I cannot push my commited changes to git.

```
> git push
Enumerating objects: 82, done.
Counting objects: 100% (82/82), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Writing objects: 100% (57/57), 7.52 KiB | 770.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 57 (delta 43), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (43/43), completed with 22 local objects.
remote: Internal Server Error
To https://***.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (Internal Server Error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://***.git'
```

I've tried some solutions from other stackoverflow questions, but following didn't work.

What I tried #1: `git pull`

```
> git pull
Current branch master is up to date.

> git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
From https://***
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Current branch master is up to date.

> git push
Enumerating objects: 82, done.
Counting objects: 100% (82/82), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Writing objects: 100% (57/57), 7.52 KiB | 770.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 57 (delta 43), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (43/43), completed with 22 local objects.
remote: Internal Server Error
To https://***.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (Internal Server Error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://***.git'
```

What I tried #2: `git remote prune origin`

```
> git remote prune origin

> git gc --auto

> git push
Enumerating objects: 82, done.
Counting objects: 100% (82/82), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Writing objects: 100% (57/57), 7.52 KiB | 770.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 57 (delta 43), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (43/43), completed with 22 local objects.
remote: Internal Server Error
To https://***.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (Internal Server Error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://***.git'
```

Comment: The remote server seems to be broken, I doubt you can fix it client side

Comment: Do you know what git service is used on the server side ? github ? gitlab ? bitbucket ? azure devops ? gitea ? some other server ? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a "500 Internal Server Error"

> A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable.

You need to check on the remote hosting service you are using.

Or, if it is an on-premise Git repository hosting service, contact their administrators.

Comment: I contacted git administrator, and that was a server-side issue. Thank you for advice.

Comment: @Ellisein Great. Well done.